# How to getting output when we run this code?This code accepts only input not showing o/p when we enter?

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

```
//program for displaying words and lines
%{
    int w=0,ch=0;
%}
%%
[^ \t\n.:;,]+ {w++;ch+=yyleng;}
[ \t\n.:;,]+  {ch++;}
%%
main()
{
    printf("Enter the data \n");
    yylex();
    printf("No of words: %d \nNo of characters: %d\n",w,ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yylex function generated by (f)lex doesn't return until it encounters a rule which includes a return statement, or yyterminate() is called. (The default EOF rule calls yyterminate.)

Your program does exactly what is expected: it consumes input until the end-of-file, and then yylex() returns and it prints the final summary.

By the way, you're not counting word separator characters correctly. Either remove the `+` repetition operator from the second pattern, or change its action to `ch += yyleng;`

If you actually want to issue a report at the end of a line, remove `\n` from the second pattern and add a `\n` rule whose action is `{ return; }`